# Proving limit existence of a solution for $y'(x) = f(x,y(x))$ at the end-point of the solution's domain, when $f$ satisfies Lipschitz condition

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

> $y(x)$ is a solution for $y'(x) = f(x,y(x))$ defined for $x\in(a,b) , b<\infty$.
>   $f(x,y)$ fulfill local Lipschitz condition with respect to $y$ for $x\in(a,b)$ (see below the condition as I was taught). So, $\lim_{x\rightarrow b} y(x) = L$ when $L$ is finale or $+-\infty$.
>
> Lipschitz condition says: $\forall x_{0} \in (a,b) \exists\delta,c>0 : \forall y_1,y_2\in (y(x_0)-\delta,y(x_0)+\delta) , \forall x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta):$ 
>   $$
> |f(x,y_2)-f(x,y_1)| \le |y_2 -y_1|c
> $$

My efforts so far: Assuming the limit doesn't exists, We get that $y(b)$ is 
defined (but is not a solution for the ODE) and $\exists \varepsilon_0 >0$ such that $\forall \delta >0 \exists x_\delta\in(b-\delta,b)$ such that:

$|y(x_\delta)-y(b)| >\varepsilon_0$ and $\forall x\in (b-\delta,b) |f(x)|<M$

Defining $\delta_n =1/n$ we get a sequence $\{x_n\}_1^\infty$ such that $\{x_n\} \rightarrow b$.

Using the derivative definition: $$\forall \lambda>0, \forall x_0\in(b-\lambda,b) 
 \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{y(x)-y(x_0)}{x-x_0} =f(x_0,y(x_0)) $$ so for $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ we get: $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow x_n} \frac{y(x_n)-y(x_n)}{x-x_n} =f(x_n,y(x_n)) , \lim_{x\rightarrow x_m} \frac{y(x_m)-y(x_m)}{x-x_m} =f(x_m,y(x_m)) $$

Trying combining the last result with the assumption for Lipschitz condition:
$$|f(x_n,y(x_n))-f(x_m,y(x_m))| \le |y(x_n) -y(x_m)|c$$ and using the last result, I am pretty much stuck, I can't find any idea how to extend the problem to $x=b$ , cause $y(x)$ is not a solution for $y'(x) = f(x,y(x))$ in $x=b$

Comment: You know already that $y$ can be continuously extended to $(a, b]$. The formula for the left derivative gives $$y'_{-}(b)=\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}\frac{y(b-h)-y(b)}{h}.$$ By MVT, there is $x_h \in (b-h, b)$ such that $y(b-h)-y(b)=y'(x_h) h$.  $y'(x_h)=f(x_h,y(x_h))$, and $f$ is assumed to be continuous (Lipschitz is not needed here).  Can you finish now?

Comment: @user539887 May you explain why $y$ can be continuously extended? also, why is it right to use MVT when the only thing I know about $y(b)$ is that it is defined? (when MVT demands closed (compact) interval). thx!

Comment: Take $a_1\in(a,b)$.  There is $M>0$ such that $\lvert y'(x)\rvert\le M$ for all $x\in[a_1, b)$.  Now we show that there exists a left-side (finite) limit $\lim_{x\to b^-}y(x)$. How to do that? For any sequence $(x_n)\subset[a_1,b)$ converging to $b$ the sequence $y(x_n)$ is Cauchy, so is convergent, too. One proves now that all sequences $(y(x_n))$ obtained in such a way have a common limit (denote it by $y(b)$).  So, $y$ has been extended to a continuous function on $[a_1,b]$, differentiable on $(a_1,b)$, and one can use MVT. Lipschitz property of $f$ is not used.

Comment: @user539887 Just want to make sure I've got you guidance right:@user539887 thx again. After showing that for all $(x_n)_1^\infty\rightarrow b \Rightarrow y(x_n)\rightarrow L$ for the same L, we get a new function $y_1$ such that $y_1|_{[a_1,b)}\equiv y, y_1(b)=L$. Now applying your first comment guidance we get $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} y_1(b-h)-y_1(b) =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f(x_h,y_1(x_h))\cdot h $ from $y_1|_{[a_1,b)}\equiv y$ and $f$ continuity:  $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} y_1(b-h)-y_1(b) = 0 \Rightarrow\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} y_1(b-h)=y_1(b)$ when $y_1(b-h)=y(b-h)$ and that finished the proof. thx!